# How to use docker container's env variable while running docker exec command

Tags: bash, docker, environment-variables

I am running a `docker exec -it ...` command and I need to use an environment variable of my docker container. An example:

```
docker exec -it container_id command_here param_1 $param_2_as_env_variable
```

In the case above, it pulls `param_2_as_env_variable` from host machine, and not the docker container. Is it possible to use env variable from container itself while running `docker exec ...` command from another machine?

---

Update: I can use ouput of `docker exec -it container_id printenv | grep ...`. But I couldn't separate value and key. How can I get only value here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this could work (it assumes, the container has a shell installed)

```
docker exec -it container_id sh -c 'command_here param_1 $param_2_as_env_variable'
```

For example the following works:

```
docker exec -it test sh -c 'echo $HOSTNAME'
```

to give the host name of the container.

Comment: Nope, this still gets host machine's env variable.

Comment: Now it accepts as a plain string. Doesn't parse at all :(

Comment: Are you sure the environment variable is defined in the container?

Comment: Yes, I can see it when I run `printenv`. I updated the question, can you check?

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the variable to pass it to the docker exec command unresolved:

Try:

```
docker exec -it container_id command_here param_1 \$param_2_as_env_variable
```

Comment: This produces `illegal input exception`. So it doesn't parse `$param2` at all, it just gets it as plain string.

Comment: `This produces illegal input exception. So it doesn't parse` How does "illegal input exception" (what does "produce" the message exactly? What is the message exactly?) lead to "doesn't parse"?

Comment: Sorry, the error wasn't related this case. The answer is correct.